# How to increase text size?

Tags: unity, 11.04, customization

the option at the login screen indeed makes the text bigger and easier to read but it only seem to be in effect for the login screen. When I login to the desktop, everything is back to normal size. Is this supposed to behave this way?

Your answer will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about an accessibility feature?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about an accessibility feature. I'm sorry for not being specific on this.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are using 11.04, go to System Settings>Appearance>Fonts and increase the font size for Application, Document, Desktop and Window title.

Here it is step by step. Click on the power button on the top right and then select System Settings

[image]

Then click on Appearance:

[image]

Then click on the font you want to edit:

[image]

Then select the font size and hit Ok:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! this worked good for me. However, I'm wondering why is there such setting in the login screen (the accesibility feature) that works only in the login screen? Is not there an easier and simple configuration option for people with visual limitations to increase the text size of the whole ubuntu environment?