# How to increase text size on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

My O.S. is Lubuntu 12.04. And I'm having some problems to read the text of my screen, because it appears very small. I've read [How to increase text size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54636), but it only explains how to increase text size in Ubuntu and as Lubuntu uses another desktop environment I'm not being able to follow that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Tutorial

1. Go to Lubuntu Menu > Preferences > Customize Look and Feel
2. To change the Default Font:

   [image]
3. To change the Title Bar Font:

   [image]
4. After customizing the settings the way you want just click "Apply"

Comment: I've followed these steps, and set all of these to a very distinctive font, but the desktop, the start menu, and application fonts (eg nvidia-settings) fonts are all unchanged.

Comment: How to do it in Lubuntu 20? I cannot find this menu on this version

Answer (score 0):

looked for a way to change the panel's font size 
the only thing that was available is the 
      `lxpanelctl config` 
but when i came to change the font size it only gets up to 20
 ( which is nearly enough on big screens ) 
so found the xml file related : 
      `sudo gedit /usr/share/lxpanel/ui/panel-pref.u`
after editing this file and changing the 20 parameter to 100 (just serach for 20 and you'll see it), 
i was able to go back to the lxpanelctl config and up the font size to what was best for me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer:

- Right-click the desktop, go to Desktop Preferences > Appearance and set the "Font of label text" there.
- Right-click the Panel (Application/Start Bar), go to Panel Settings > Appearance and set the Font size. This one only goes up to 20, but it's much better than before.